# iOS/android hybrid app distribution/architecture model help or advice please

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile, cordova

I am pretty new to the mobile end of development so forgive my naivety.

I would like to know if it's possible to have a structure/distribution model like the following:

Master App (has many "middle-man" instances)
     !
     !
Middle-man ( can customize data, look & feel, via web app and redistribute)
(has many end user viewers)
     !
     !
     !
End User viewers( can download and install middle-man abc's app with middle-man's custom info)

Is this possible?  I have searched around for quite a bit but perhaps I am searching the wrong terms?

I was thinking perhaps a couple options, let me know if it's sounds wrong.

Option 1 - Middle-man provides a special key code and end user types it in after installing the app to unlock it thereby storing the unique middle-man ID and displaying only their custom info.  User only needs to enter code once. relation is stored in mysql perhaps??

Option 2 - create a build of the master template for each middle-man and provide the binary/install link along with a customized ini file to load correct ID?  Or something to that effect.

Any better options out there?  Something that allows for upgrades/new features to be passed down to all the instances easily.

Will this type of thing have any problems with the apple store if multiple middle men decide they want it on the app store?

Maybe I'm making it more complex than needed and could just use a simple "require login" for each end-user and the end user is tied to that middle man some how?

\The app could also be android app depending on middle-man requirements

Thanks in advance for any advice or links to helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

If i had understood your question right, its a straight forward mobile app tied up with the backend.

- User credentials for the middleman which shall associate with your
  special key code.
- Associate your actors(users) with roles and permission over accessing
  content in the backend.
- Your mobile app will pull the content only associated for the logged
  in user.

Apart from this, you can store the content for offline etc.. Take phonegap approach and it pretty much does what you wanted to do.